# Google Sheets API - Timeout

Tags: google-sheets-api, gspread

I regularly use gspread and lately I've been getting these read timeout errors but only on certain sheets. Sometimes I'll be able to read & write to a sheet for a bit and then it'll hang until I get this read timeout error and then all subsequent attempts to read from that sheet will hang immediately and again give me this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    444                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 445                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    446         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    439                 try:
--> 440                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    441                 except BaseException as e:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1372             try:
-> 1373                 response.begin()
   1374             except ConnectionError:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    310         while True:
--> 311             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    312             if status != CONTINUE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    271     def _read_status(self):
--> 272         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    273         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)
   1011                   self.__class__)
-> 1012             return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   1013         else:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    873         try:
--> 874             return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    875         except SSLError as x:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    630         if buffer is not None:
--> 631             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    632         else:

timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ReadTimeoutError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    755             retries = retries.increment(
--> 756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    757             )

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    531             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 532                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    533             elif read is not None:

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 735             raise value
    736         finally:

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    705                 headers=headers,
--> 706                 chunked=chunked,
    707             )

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    446         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:
--> 447             self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
    448             raise

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _raise_timeout(self, err, url, timeout_value)
    336             raise ReadTimeoutError(
--> 337                 self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value
    338             )

ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sheets.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ReadTimeout                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-dc10e6e8ee1a> in <module>
----> 1 max_sheet.range('A1:B1')

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/utils.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    396             pass
    397 
--> 398         return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    399 
    400     return wrapper

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py in range(self, name)
    686         range_label = absolute_range_name(self.title, name)
    687 
--> 688         data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(range_label)
    689 
    690         start, end = name.split(':')

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py in values_get(self, range, params)
    190         """
    191         url = SPREADSHEET_VALUES_URL % (self.id, quote(range))
--> 192         r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
    193         return r.json()
    194 

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
     68             data=data,
     69             files=files,
---> 70             headers=headers,
     71         )
     72 

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    553 
    554         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 555         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    556 
    557     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py in request(self, method, url, data, headers, max_allowed_time, timeout, **kwargs)
    486                 headers=request_headers,
    487                 timeout=timeout,
--> 488                 **kwargs
    489             )
    490         remaining_time = guard.remaining_timeout

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 
    544         return resp

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653 
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    527                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    528             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
--> 529                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
    530             else:
    531                 raise

ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sheets.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)
```

I tried taking gspread out of it for troubleshooting but it still gives me the same issue even when I'm using code from the python quickstart example from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python (below). The timeout issue is the same whether I do it from my local machine or my jupyter server on digitalocean.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('XXXXXXX', scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='XXXXXXX',
                            range='Active Accounts - working copy!A1:A2').execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

The above code results in this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-5c352599e283> in <module>
      1 sheet = service.spreadsheets()
      2 result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='XXXXXX',
----> 3                             range='Active Accounts - working copy!A1:A2').execute()
      4 values = result.get('values', [])

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    132                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    133                     logger.warning(message)
--> 134             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    135 
    136         return positional_wrapper

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    899             method=str(self.method),
    900             body=self.body,
--> 901             headers=self.headers,
    902         )
    903 

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    202         if exception:
    203             if retry_num == num_retries:
--> 204                 raise exception
    205             else:
    206                 continue

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    175         try:
    176             exception = None
--> 177             resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    178         # Retry on SSL errors and socket timeout errors.
    179         except _ssl_SSLError as ssl_error:

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, **kwargs)
    196         # Make the request.
    197         response, content = self.http.request(
--> 198             uri, method, body=body, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
    199 
    200         # If the response indicated that the credentials needed to be

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1989                         headers,
   1990                         redirections,
-> 1991                         cachekey,
   1992                     )
   1993         except Exception as e:

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1649 
   1650         (response, content) = self._conn_request(
-> 1651             conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
   1652         )
   1653 

~/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1587                 pass
   1588             try:
-> 1589                 response = conn.getresponse()
   1590             except (http.client.BadStatusLine, http.client.ResponseNotReady):
   1591                 # If we get a BadStatusLine on the first try then that means

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1371         try:
   1372             try:
-> 1373                 response.begin()
   1374             except ConnectionError:
   1375                 self.close()

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    309         # read until we get a non-100 response
    310         while True:
--> 311             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    312             if status != CONTINUE:
    313                 break

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    270 
    271     def _read_status(self):
--> 272         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    273         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
    274             raise LineTooLong("status line")

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    584         while True:
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:
    588                 self._timeout_occurred = True

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)
   1010                   "non-zero flags not allowed in calls to recv_into() on %s" %
   1011                   self.__class__)
-> 1012             return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   1013         else:
   1014             return socket.recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    872             raise ValueError("Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.")
    873         try:
--> 874             return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    875         except SSLError as x:
    876             if x.args[0] == SSL_ERROR_EOF and self.suppress_ragged_eofs:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    629         """
    630         if buffer is not None:
--> 631             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    632         else:
    633             v = self._sslobj.read(len)

timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?